# Isn't it a blank page?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> One day, your friend John messaged you.
>
> John: Wanna solve this puzzle? The answer contains five words
>
> [image]
>
> You: Are you playing tricks on me??? This is a blank page!
>
> John: This puzzle is not too hard. Do not let me down!
>
> You: Wait, is the answer "This page is left blank"?
>
> John: No. gtg!

---

Actually this puzzle is created by my friend (of course without the dialogues). I could not solve it, and he told me how to solve it. This puzzle is so interesting that I want to share with you guys!

---

Hint zone: Hints will **not** be posted as @Deusovi cracked the puzzle within 30 minutes of posting!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The blank page

> has some slightly off-white pixels. These form a message:
>  [image]
>
>  The off-white text says: `Answer is name of this song: dQw4w9WgXcQ`. As any long-time internet denizen would know, that is the suffix of the Youtube URL for **Never Gonna Give You Up**, by Rick Astley.